# Time-dependend coefficients in a Cox Model

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I have a Cox proportional hazards model with six categorical variables. Using the cox.zph-function from the "Survival"-package I found nonproportionality for four of them. After reading a nice [article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) I tried using a stepfunction for $\beta(t)$ to beginn with for only two variables:

```
vet2 <- survSplit(Surv(lifetime_months, event) ~., trainSurv,
              cut=c(20, 40), episode ="timegroup")
cox_ext<-coxph(Surv(tstart,lifetime_months, event) ~ BS24*strata(timegroup) + dauer_anstellung, data=vet2, x=TRUE, method="efron")
```

This worked pretty good for me. 
Now I tested the proportional hazards assumption again (for simplicity only two variables are included):

```
cox.zph(cox_ext, transform="identity")
                                               rho   chisq        p
BS24Sonstige                              -0.00289  0.1016 7.50e-01
BS240                                      0.01674  3.3816 6.59e-02
BS24FM/abgG                               -0.00549  0.3670 5.45e-01
dauer_anstellung.katmissing                0.04684 26.6142 2.48e-07
dauer_anstellung.kat18-46                  0.04110 20.4716 6.05e-06
dauer_anstellung.kat46-78                  0.03294 13.1078 2.94e-04
dauer_anstellung.kat78-168                 0.05866 41.4677 1.20e-10
dauer_anstellung.kat168-260                0.05244 33.1972 8.33e-09
dauer_anstellung.kat>260                   0.05589 37.8213 7.75e-10
BS24Sonstige:strata(timegroup)timegroup=2 -0.00412  0.2062 6.50e-01
BS240:strata(timegroup)timegroup=2        -0.01083  1.4201 2.33e-01
BS24FM/abgG:strata(timegroup)timegroup=2  -0.00441  0.2360 6.27e-01
BS24Sonstige:strata(timegroup)timegroup=3 -0.00105  0.0135 9.08e-01
BS240:strata(timegroup)timegroup=3        -0.00689  0.5763 4.48e-01
BS24FM/abgG:strata(timegroup)timegroup=3   0.00164  0.0327 8.56e-01
GLOBAL                                          NA 87.4091 3.01e-12
```

Since my variable BS24 is categorical with four Levels the test result depends on my reference level. For the cox model without timevarying coefficients I computed the overall effect according to Grambsch, Therneau: "Modeling Survival Data: Extending the Cox model" with a three degree of freedom test for all three coefficients:

```
cox<-coxph(Surv(lifetime_months, event) ~ BS24 + dauer_anstellung, data=trainSurv, x=TRUE, method="efron")


phtest<-cox.zph(cox, transform="identity")
xx<-phtest$x-mean(phtest$x) #g-mean(g)
temp1<-xx %*% phtest$y[,1:3] #times scaled Schoen
temp2<-solve(cox$var[1:3,1:3]) #matrix inverse
test<-temp1 %*% temp2 %*% t(temp1)/(sum(trainSurv$event)*sum(xx^2))
round(c(test=test, p=1-pchisq(test,3)),3)
```

My question is now, how to get the overall effect of BS24 on proportionality in the new extended cox model with the timevarying coefficients for BS24. In the result it looks like the assumption is fulfilled for the current reference level. Hope you can help me out with that.

Added:
After fitting my model to my trainingset I'd like to make a prediction based on my testset. Since the time variable on the right handside of my extended cox model - timegroup - is unknown at initial starting time $t=0$, I'm wondering if that's even possible. 
I usually use the "Score"-function from package riskRegression to compute a time-dependent AUC to evaluate the prediction performance of my models.

Comment: If you do not get a useful response here I suggest posting on the R-help mailing list where Therneau sometimes replies to questions.